# Java 8 stream. all elements EXCEPT other elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm interested in identifying an approach that returns a list of elements excluding the elements in another list.

for example

```
List<Integer> multiplesOfThree = ... // 3,6,9,12 etc
List<Integer> evens = ... // 2,4,6,8 etc
List<Integer> others = multiplesOfThree.except(evens) // should return a list of elements that are not in the other list
```

how do you do this? 
i found an approach that's a bit clunky and difficult to read....

```
multiplesOfThree.stream()
.filter(intval -> evens.stream().noneMatch(even -> even.intValue() == intval.intValue()))
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`Stream`'s `filter` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), passing a `Predicate` that ensures that the element doesn't exist in `evens`.

```
List<Integer> others = multiplesOfThree.stream()
        .filter(i -> !evens.contains(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But assuming you have a mutable `List` (e.g. `ArrayList`), you don't even need streams, just [`Collections'`s `removeAll` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-).

```
multiplesOfThree.removeAll(evens);
```

Comment: removeAll is a excelent solution.

Comment: `removeAll` is nice from a performance perspective, for cases where you really want to mutate the source collection. However, there are many good reasons for why an immutable approach (returning a new collection with the matching elements removed) is preferable instead.

Answer (score 8):

You could use

```
multipleOfThree.stream()
               .filter(((Predicate<Integer>) evens::contains).negate())
```

or more efficient for big `even` lists

```
HashSet<Integer> evenSet = new HashSet<>(even);
multipleOfThree.stream()
               .filter(((Predicate<Integer>) evenSet::contains).negate())
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few solutions.

First, without using streams, you can just create a new list and remove all elements from another collection from it...

```
final List<Integer> multiplesOfThree = Arrays.asList(3,6,9,12);
final List<Integer> evens = Arrays.asList(2,4,6,8,10,12);
final List<Integer> others1 = new ArrayList<>(multiplesOfThree);
others1.removeAll(evens);
```

Another solution would be to pass the stream through a filter():

```
final List<Integer> others2 = multiplesOfThree
     .stream()
     .filter(x -> !evens.contains(x))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(You may want to consider making `evens` a `Set` in this case).

And finally, you could modify the logic above to represent the "evens" as a function rather than a collection of all even numbers. This is essentially the same as above, but you don't have to have a second collection.

```
final List<Integer> others3 = multiplesOfThree
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```